# toggle between "active" and "inactive" records in an index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I am extremely "green" when t comes to Ruby & Rails, I could do this easily in VB, but I want to learn rails....

I have a simple index view which shows all the clients in my database, and I figured out how to replace the index action in the controller to display only the clients who are marked as "active" (a field in the clients table), but my head is swimming trying to figure out routing and/or control actions for switching between the two or three recordsets (in VB terms).

My ultimate goal would be to have radio buttons on the index view where the user chooses between "active", "inactive" or "all".

Currently I have this in the clients controller...

```
@clients = Client.find(:all, :conditions => { :active => true })
#@clients = Client.find(:all, :conditions => { :active => false })
#@clients = Client.all.order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction)
```

If I comment out two of the lines, the remaining one does exactly as I want.

**4 specific questions:**  (1) How do I write a conditional statement to make this switching occur, (2) WHERE should this be implemented, controller?  Routing?  Elsewhere?, (3) can this be implemented with user selectable radio buttons in the index view?, and (4) how do I add my "order" condition back in.  (I tried just daisy-chaining it onto the end, but that doesn't work.)

Thanks in advance,
MDS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a dropdown in your index view that has all 3 statuses (radio buttons probably aren't that different but I don't have an example right now):

```
<%= form_tag("/clients", method: "get") do %>
  <%= select_tag(:active, options_for_select([['Active', true], ['Inactive', false], ['All', '']], params[:active]), :prompt => 'Status') %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

(Assuming your controller index page is at /clients, if not change the value in the form_tag)

You then add a scope to your Client model that takes an argument, this way you're not cluttering up your controller:

```
scope :active, lambda { |active| where(:active => active)}
```

In your controller, you then call the scope with the param value if it's set:

```
@clients = Client.all.order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction)
@clients = @clients.active(params[:active]) unless params[:active].blank?
```

No need to mess with routing since you're just passing a params value.

Comment: thanks @tirdadc, I'll give this a try, just one question... what is "lambda" (other than a greek letter, or what a lamb sez when it doesn't know the answer?)

Comment: Lambda functions are the same as anonymous functions, you can find more details [here](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/). a Lambda is typically used in a named scope to pass an argument to it (in this case, the `active` value).

Comment: Once you get a chance to try this and if it works out for you, please accept the answer.

Comment: Just finished implementing, good news is there are no errors (after adding a missing square bracket), bad news nothing happens when you make a selection from the dropdown.  All records always display no matter what is selected in dropdown.  Do I need to put a callback in or something to fire "on change"???

Comment: You need an actual form tag and a submit button to send the param back to your controller. Let me edit the answer to add that now.

Comment: Geez!  Now I get a syntax error, but I don't see where there are any paranthesis missing as is implied in error msg...  app/views/clients/index.html.erb:12: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting ')'
...fer.append=( submit_tag("Search") );@output_buffer.safe_appe...

Comment: was missing an " after the `get`. Try now.

Comment: Okay, found it... missing closing quote two lines above in form_tag line.  Now the select displays and the submit button fires, but the only value that works is the "All" option.  I just verified that my schema does indeed refer to the "active" field in the clients table.  And I have records which are both "true" and "false" in that field.  Why don't the first two select options return any records....?

Comment: I also checked, the schema does indeed show the field as boolean, too.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple of strategies.

1) Load all the records onto the page, give them a class based on their active status, and hide some of them.  The radio buttons have javascript attached, which shows or hides records with a particular class.

2) Load one set of records, and make the radio buttons trigger a request to the server to reload the contents of the list, passing through different params, eg "active=true" or "active=false"  (when params[:active] isn't present you could load all of them).  It's nicer if this is done via ajax but you could have it reload the whole page.

I wouldn't do this via routing since it's just a params thing.